# SmileBASIC sample programs source

Tags: nintendo

SmileBASIC (for Nintendo 3DS) comes with some sample programs.

I assume these are stored somewhere on the Micro SD card, but I cannot find them.  Where are they?  I would like to view the source on a PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programs are not stored individually as files on the SD Card, they are stored in the game's extended save data.